# lint-staged generates new .eslintcache file on commit

Tags: vue.js, eslint, lint-staged

I'm creating a new Vue project via `npm init vue@latest` and select *everything* (Eslint with Prettier)

I'm using the following setup

- OS: Win11
- node: v17.4
- npm: v8.4

I setup *lint-staged* via `npx mrm@2 lint-staged`. For testing purposes I add a new file inside the *src* directory

```
// calc.js

function 
add
(numOne, 
  numTwo) {
  return numOne + 
  
              numTwo;
}
```

When committing the new file the linter fixes the code style as expected. But after that I manually have to delete a generated *.eslintcache* file.

Older posts say I should add

`*.eslintcache`

to the *.gitignore* file. But I compared the generated *.gitignore* file with the generated one from the Vue CLI and both don't have this line. When using the Vue CLI the cache file doesn't appear.

So are there any other solutions or is there something I missed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.eslintcache` file is created from ESLint's [`--cache` flag](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#--cache), which is included in the default linter command of `lint-staged`:

```json
// package.json
{
  "lint-staged": {                        
    "*.{vue,js,jsx,cjs,mjs}": "eslint --cache --fix",
    "*.{js,css,md}": "prettier --write"
  }
}
```

You can either remove the `--cache` flag:

```json
// package.json
{
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{vue,js,jsx,cjs,mjs}": "eslint --fix",
    "*.{js,css,md}": "prettier --write"
  }
}
```

...or set the cache file location with the [`--cache-location` flag](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#--cache-location) (e.g., specify `node_modules/.cache`):

```json
// package.json
{
  "lint-staged": {                                          
    "*.{vue,js,jsx,cjs,mjs}": "eslint --cache --fix --cache-location ./node_modules/.cache/.eslintcache",
    "*.{js,css,md}": "prettier --write"
  }
}
```